# Powershell get address list work in PS 5.1 but not in 7

Tags: powershell, outlook, comobject

I'm trying to retrieve info about Global Address List in Outlook.
It works in Powershell 5.1 but not in 7.0.3.

The Code is:

```
$Outlook = NEW-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List")
```

Output in PS 5.1:

```
Application          : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                : 7
Session              : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass
Parent               : System.__ComObject
AddressEntries       : System.__ComObject
ID                   : 00000000E3FDA12B9AF86342819F3DEFE5D82FE001000000000100002F00
Index                : 2
IsReadOnly           : True
Name                 : Global Address List
AddressListType      : 0
ResolutionOrder      : 1
IsInitialAddressList : True
PropertyAccessor     : System.__ComObject
```

Output in PS 7.0.3:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'AddressLists'.
```

Do you havy any idea why this not working in new Powershell version?

Comment: Can you run the code in powershell ISE as administrator and share the result?

Comment: It is working for me in all the versions 
`PS C:\Users\rdutta1> $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists("Global Address List")


Application          : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                : 7
Session              : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass
Parent               : System.__ComObject
AddressEntries       : System.__ComObject
ID                   : 000000003A22616F48849B45B4E190BBEA50016601000000000100002F677569643D3334454639343839303444423433
                       37373931323633413734424246393132344
so on and so forth`

Comment: I can replicate the issue. Does this work for you? It gives equal results

$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists | Where {$_.name -eq 'Global Address List'}

Comment: Greate now I'm wondering how it did work at all. Like the Error said `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")` has no such method: `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") | gm -MemberType Method`

Comment: However you still get it with a `where`: `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists | where {$_.name -like "Global*"}`

Comment: @Pba Thanks your solution worked

Comment: @Mich94 I'll post it as an official answer for future references.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the issue. Does this work for you? It gives equal results `$Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists | Where {$_.name -eq 'Global Address List'}`